# WPF Textbox Background Color based on text length

Tags: wpf, colors, textbox, background

I have a textbox in a listview itemtemplate.  I want to change the background color of the textbox to red whenever the length is greater than 75 characters, and I need the background color to update as the user types.  What is the best way to achieve this in WPF?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe something like this would work. It would require you to write your own background color converter.

```
<TextBox 
    Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self},
        Path=Text, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
        Converter={StaticResource backgroundColorConverter}}" 
    ... 
/>
```

Another option would be to use a DataTrigger like below. This would also require a converter to check if the length of the string was more than 75.

```
<TextBox>
    ....
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="YourDefaultColor" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=YourTextBox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource textLengthColorConverter}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: The first one fires only after the textbox loses focus.  I get a "A value of type 'DataTrigger' cannot be added a collection or dictionary of type 'SetterBaseCollection' on the second one.

Comment: Use UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged for the first one. The default is LostFocus for TextBox's. I'd need to see your code to help with the 2nd error.

Comment: What about the 2nd one? Did you ever get that one working too?

Comment: I'll have to go back and test it later.  I've spent too much time trying to get this to work, and I need to move on.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think the second one just needs <Style.Triggers> tags wrapped abour the <DataTrigger>.

Comment: Ah, absolutely correct. I forgot that while I was typing it in. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of "Run" tag with in text block, which applies background according to length of text