# Bind WPF Label visibility to entered password length

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind the visibility of a label to the typed length of a PasswordBox control. I'm binding the Visibility property of the label to the output of a converter targeted at the SecurePassword.Length property of the passwordbox.

The binding works fine, but only once, when the app first starts. It doesn't stay in sync. If I seed the password with a long enough value (as in my example), the message is displayed, but it doesn't update as I type or delete text. Clearly, I'm missing something.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916217/wpf-textbox-background-color-based-on-text-length) question as a template for my implementation.

My Xaml:

```
<PasswordBox Name="PwdPassword" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="120" 
             Password="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"></PasswordBox>

<Label Name="LblPasswordMsg" Content="Message" FontWeight="Bold">
    <Label.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ElementName=PwdPassword, Mode=OneWay,
                   Path=SecurePassword.Length, Converter={StaticResource IntLengthVisibilityConverter}}" />
         </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

My Converter:

```c#
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Visibility))]
public class IntLengthVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do the conversion from int to visibility
        int length = (int)value;
        Visibility visible = length >= 25 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        return visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do the conversion from visibility to int
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is SecurePassword.Length is not a dependency property, so no automatic notification occurs when its value changes.