# Is there a way to change Texblock foreground based on It own Text using XAML only?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have this Textblock that I want to change.

if the text shows `"file already exist"` the foreground should be `red`,

else if the text shows `"file saved"` the foreground should be in `green`.

Comment: Xaml only - no [converters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1916327/1997232)? Perhaps a trigger which directly compare value of `Text`.

Comment: @Sinatr I tried using boolean converters, but It only has 2 outputs. Is there other converter I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are after with a `Trigger`

```
<TextBlock Text="file aleady exist">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="file saved">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="file aleady exist">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```